# How to execute a background task periodically in Android?

Tags: android, service, background

I'm making an app that starts a Service that sends SMS message periodically under specific conditions. It all works, but I have problems to run the job (check conditions + message sending) periodically every minute when the phone is in "standby" (display turned off). With screen on it all works without problems.

I tried using java Timer and TimerTask, but when the screen is off nothing works and when I turn it on, all skipped task are executed in a row (for example, if I turn off the screen at 20:00 and turn on it at 20:30, TimerTask is executed 30 times at 20:30).

I tried also with Handler using Handler.postDelayed method. In this case nothing is done, and when I turn on the screen skipped task are not executed.

So, how can I run a Runnable every minute also when device screen is off???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `AlarmManager`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: I knew AlarmManager is for performing tasks that should wake up the device turning on the screen and launching activities. I do not need that, the device must rest in standby (I only send a "vibrating" notification in the notification bar). Anyway, I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: If you do something with the processor you already woke up the app, even a notification is a wake call. You actually wake up the processor not the screen.

Comment: Done with AlarmManager. Now I hope it will not drain the battery :) Thank you.